# Elixir - What does the 'use' keyword do?

Tags: module, macros, functional-programming, erlang, elixir

I suspect it's an elementary question, but it's been hard to find a succinct, canonical answer online.

From what little I understand;

- It's distinct from both 'require' and 'import'
- It's used to import the contents of modules.
- It's a macro

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: For what it's worth @SasaJuric did an excellent series of blog posts about macros and he covers the use statement in depth here: http://www.theerlangelist.com/2014/06/understanding-elixir-macros-part-2.html

Comment: Why is there an Erlang tag on this?

Comment: Figured there might be a decent number of people with an interest in both languages.. Also couldn't be sure if there was an equivalent feature in Erlang itself, or it's virtual machine.

Comment: elixir poor document. I can not find answers after search ten minutes in google and `getting-started`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It `require`s the given module and then calls the `__using__/1` callback on it allowing the module to inject some code into the current context. See https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#use.

Example:

```
defmodule Test do
  use Utility, argument: :value
end
```

is about the same as

```
defmodule Test do
  require Utility
  Utility.__using__(argument: :value)
end
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer. A follow up question... When you use Mix to set up  a new OTP app, do I have to 'require/use/import' the modules that I create in the /lib folder? because after I compile, it looks like I can (for example) call A.B.method from A.C without an explicit import directive.

Comment: `require` has nothing to do with functions, it just makes the macros from the `require`’d module available to the current lexical scope. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html

Comment: As long as your files are compiled you can call any function by specifying `Module.function_name` fully. If you use import you can use `function_name` omitting the `Module` which might be cleaner for cases where you use functions from a certain module a lot in some file for example.

Comment: @obrok - Awesome reply (to the question in the comment). Exactly what I was aiming to confirm.